# Maps inducing identity in Hochschild and cyclic theories

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology

Let $A$ be a unital algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, $M$ be an $A$ bimodule, $C^n(A, M)$ be a space of all $n$-linear maps $f \colon A^n \to M$ (to be called $n$-cochains) and define $b \colon C^n(A, M) \to C^{n + 1}(A, M)$ by the formula
\begin{align*}
  (bf)(a_1, \dotsc, a_n, a_{n+1})
  :={}& a_1 f(a_2, \dotsc, a_{n+1}) \\
    {}& + \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^j f(a_1, \dotsc,a_{j-1}, a_j a_{j+1}, a_{j+2}, \dotsc, a_{n+1}) \\
    {}&+(-1)^{n+1}f(a_1, \dotsc, a_n) a_{n+1} \,.
\end{align*}
One checks that $b^2 = 0$ so we get a cochain complex – the cohomology of this complex is called *Hochschild cohomology*. Hochschild *homology* is defined in the following way: $C_0(A, M) = M$ and $C_n(A, M) = M \otimes A^{\otimes n}$ and
\begin{align*}
  b(m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n)
  :={}& m a_1 \otimes a_2 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n \\
    {}& + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (-1)^j m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{j-1} \otimes a_j a_{j+1} \otimes a_{j+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n \\
    {}& + (-1)^n a_n m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n-1} \,.
\end{align*}
Again $b^2 = 0$ and therefore we get chain complex: the homology of this complex is Hochschild homology. For an algebra map $f \colon A \to B$ (or more general, for a chain map) we get natural induced maps in both homology and cohomology.

> Suppose that I know that some map $f \colon A \to A$ induces identity in Hochschild *homology*: is it also true that then it induces identity in Hochschild *cohomology*?

If it would happen that it is not true for general bimodule $M$, I would like to know whether is it true in the simplest case $M = A$ and $M = A^*$ (the dual module) for homology and cohomology respectively.

The second part is quite similar, but instead of Hochschild (co)homology I would like to know the same for the so called *cyclic* (co)homology. For the cyclic theory one assumes $M = A$ for homology and $M = A^*$ for cohomology: using some natural identifications for $\mathrm{Hom}(A^{\otimes n}, A^*) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(A^{\otimes (n + 1)}, \mathbb{C})$ the formula for the differential (for example for cohomology) reads:
\begin{align*}
  (bf)(a_0, a_1, \dotsc, a_{n+1})
  ={}& \sum_{j=0}^n f(a_0, \dotsc, a_{j-1}, a_j a_{j+1}, a_{j+2}, \dotsc, a_{n+1}) \\
   {}& + (-1)^{n+1} f(a_{n+1}a_0, a_1, \dotsc, a_n) \,.
\end{align*}
Now we introduce the (zero degree) cyclic operator $\lambda$ where
$$
  (\lambda f)(a_0, \dotsc, a_n) := (-1)^n f(a_n, a_0, \dotsc, a_{n-1}) \,.
$$
We consider cochains $f$ such that $\lambda f = f$ – these are called *cyclic* cochains and the space of cyclic cochains forms a subcomplex. Therefore we can consider its cohomology which by definition is the *cyclic cohomology*. The cyclic *homology* is defined in the same manner. One can again show that any algebra map induces maps on the level of homology and cohomology. And my question is:

> Suppose that we know that some map $f \colon A \to A$ induces identity in *cyclic* homology. Is it true that it also induces identity in cyclic *cohomology*?

My question is inspired by the following discussion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243593/inner-automorphisms-acts-as-identity-on-hochschild-homology